# unable to render html from function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to loop thru JSON object and return values in `h1` and display on UI. This is how my function looks like:

```
const error_messages = Object.entries(props.feedback?.messages.json || {}).forEach((key, value) => {
    console.log(key, value)
    return (<h1>{value}</h1>)
}
)
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
<div>
{error_messages}
</div>
```

I can see the values being printed in the console but no `h1`s are rendered in the div.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using forEach. That's function will return nothing to assign.

Let try change it to `map` instead.